# How to set java VM arguments for a webapplication in BEA weblogic 8.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, bea

Can any body tell me how to set java VM arguments  in BEA weblogic(8.3),actually i'm newer to bea weblogic,usually in tomcat we will set the VM AArguments in catalina.bat by using JAVA_OPTS  like this:'-Dmyarg="value"' ,how to set this type of VM arguments in weblogic,can anybody help me,

Any help will be appreciated,Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two urls for configuring the arguments/setting the BEA weblogic.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/userguide/wlconfg.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/userguide/start.html

Comment: ok.. i'll be available here. just comment in case you find any problem.